# Python Pandas split list by delimiter into own columns

Tags: python, pandas, list

new to python and still learning. Have tried many posts already but none are working. Might need help with the syntax etc. 2 parts to my question:

First part - I want to split column 'resources' by every unique value and make new columns from them. Similar to the picture below with the columns highlighted yellow
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZyYr.png)

```
CustID, Resources, 100, 200, 30, 50
222, 100;200;30;50, 1 , 1, 1, ,1
```

The second way - i want to split 'resources' by every unique value into one column. This might lead to duplication of rows which is fine... Similar to the below picture
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kurGf.png)

```
CustID, Resources, New Column
222, 100;200;30;50, 100
222, 100;200;30;50, 200
222, 100;200;30;50, 30
222, 100;200;30;50, 50
```

Comment: `df.assign(resources=df['resources'].str.split(';')).explode('resources')`

Comment: Hi Erfan - sorry just tried. Didnt work

Comment: Add data as text pls, it's not possible to copy a picture to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Hi just added - thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, use `str.get_dummies`:

```
dummies = df['Resources'].str.get_dummies(sep=";")
df = pd.concat([df, dummies], axis=1)

   CustID      Resources  100  200  30  50
0     222  100;200;30;50    1    1   1   1
```

---

For the second question, the `explode` solution given in comments works:

```
df = df.assign(
    Resources=df['Resources'].str.split(';')
).explode('Resources', ignore_index=True)
   CustID Resources
0     222       100
1     222       200
2     222        30
3     222        50
```